# Use LINQ let with null return values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, let

I am trying to execute a method inside LINQ as

```
var result = from fruit in fruits
             let type = GetType(fruit)
             select new {
                 fruit = fruit,
                 type = type != null ? type.Name : "N/A"
             };

FruitType GetType(Fruit fruit)
{
    if (fruit == a)
      return TypeA;
    else 
      return null;
}
```

This throws an error because: if `result` is `null`, `let` doesn't allow access to `type.Name` even if it is after a `not null` check.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? Also, please post the actual error message and exception type.

Comment: Is this EF or Linq to Objects?

Comment: I don't think the code you posted accurately represents the code you're having trouble with. I created a Fiddle that represents your code above and it works just fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/goKgRx

Comment: How would `result` be null? Do you mean another variable?

Comment: Also you could just do `type = GetType(fruit)?.Name ?? "N/A"` if you're using c# 6

Comment: Good heavens **never make a method called GetType**.  It will shadow `object.GetType()`.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert It is dummy code :D

Comment: @CraigW. The error message is "Both left and right part of binary expression is null. Unable to translate query. I guess it is issue wit hthe ORM." Thanks for the fiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just return a default value instead of null?

```
FruitType GetType(Fruit fruit)
{
    if(fruit == a)
        return TypeA;
    return new FruitType {Name = "N/A"};
}
```

then your query becomes...

```
var result = from fruit in fruits
             let type = Gettype(fruit)
             select new {
                 fruit = fruit,
                 type = type.Name
             };
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand this should work, but in my scenario, I am returning a Model (db table) and I cannot use new default type as it will create an entry in the table. Any other workaround involving changes in the linq query possibly?

Comment: You are selecting a Fruit from the db. Is this the Model your referring to? Once you select it you transform it into an anonymous type (that's `new {..}` part). My answer has the same effect as your original solution. I don't see any `update` in your question...